# How can we retrieve like count or page is already liked status of Facebook like button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Placed the Facebook like button in native app with following:

```
FBSDKLikeControl *button = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] init];
button.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers";
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

How can we retrieve like count or is already liked status of button?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755753/how-to-get-likes-count-when-searching-facebook-graph-api-with-search-xxx

Comment: This is using graph api. The button is already showing count with status, already liked or not. I just need to look for the way to retrieve from this button object. What is the possiblity?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421303/facebook-like-button-in-ios-app-using-facebook-sdk

Comment: under the second link page one sample project also available , please check , in before I m not work in like button , so try second link it will be helpful for you

Comment: FYI: Facebook does not allow like gating any more.